# cannot import numpy scipy theano

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I want to use Theano on my Macbook. Mac OSX 10.6, it's a old version.

I installed Numpy, Scipy and Theano by using $pip install, and they were successfully installed in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  .
But I type $which python, it shows /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python , 
I think it is because I install Python by using Python.dmg installation downloaded from Python.org.

How to change the python version? Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart your terminal shell before trying to import?

Comment: Yes, I did, it's not work. Should I uninstall the Python to use the Apple built-in python? I have no idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set a particular Python as the default, one way is to change your environment PATH variable by adding to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/path/to/python2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

where `/path/to/python2.7` is the path to your new install (perhaps `/usr/local/bin/`?). I've started using Anaconda to avoid this kind of problem: you could look into this as well.